# Python , Web Parsing

Tags: python-3.x, web

I was watching a tutorial on web parsing in python . This is the code to get live stock data . And the code runs fine .

```
   import re
   import urllib.request

    # https://www.google.com/finance?q=
    url = "https://www.google.com/finance?q="
    stock = input("Enter Your Stock : ")
    url = url + stock
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    newData = data.decode('utf-8')
    # meta itemprop="price"
    m = re.search('meta itemprop="price"', newData)
    start = m.start()
    end = start + 50
    newStock = newData[start:end]
    m = re.search('content="', newStock)
    start = m.end()
    newStock1 = newStock[start:]
    m = re.search('/', newStock1)
    start = 0
    end = m.end() - 3
    final = newStock1[0:end]
    print("The Value Of " + stock + " Is " + final)
```

But I dont understand these two parts in the code  :

```
    start = m.start()
     end = start + 50  # Why + 50 ?

    start = 0
   end = m.end() - 3   # Why - 3 ?
```

Can anyone give me an explanation ? Please elaborate

Comment: Where do you find this tutorial?

Comment: Its actually a part of a course

Comment: Please provide a working stock.

Answer (score 0):

So, first question:

```
start = m.start()
end = start + 50 # Why + 50?
```

In order to easier understand why the +50 is there, you need to look a bit ahead and a bit after:

```
newData = data.decode('utf-8')
# meta itemprop="price"
m = re.search('meta itemprop="price"', newData)
start = m.start()
end = start + 50
newStock = newData[start:end]
```

Line by line:

- `newData` contains the UTF-8 representation of the crawled page (for example https://www.google.com/finance?q=aapl if we're trying to get the value of Apple stock).
- `m` is the match object: where in `newData` the occurrence of `meta itemprop="price"` starts, where it ends + a bunch of other information (check out the documentation for more detailed information: [python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects), [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects))
- `start` is then the position in `newData` where the match starts
- `end` if start + 50 because that's the assumed maximum length of the HTML element containing the price. For example if I look at Apple, that is:
  `<meta itemprop="price" content="116.73" />`, whose length is 42 characters.
- `newStock` now will be `meta itemprop="price" content="116.73" />`

Continuing from here to the second question:

```
start = 0
end = m.end() - 3   # Why - 3 ?
```

As with the previous example, let's get a bit more context:

```
newStock = newData[start:end]
m = re.search('content="', newStock)
start = m.end()
newStock1 = newStock[start:]
m = re.search('/', newStock1)
start = 0
end = m.end() - 3
final = newStock1[0:end]
```

Line by line:

- We've already mentioned that `newStock` now will be `meta itemprop="price" content="116.73" />`
- `m` is the match object for the new regex: where in `newStock` the occurrence of `content="` starts, ends etc.
- `start` is the *end* of the match
- `newStock1` then is a substring of `newStock` which starts with the first character after `content="` and ends at the end of the string, so `newStock1` is `116.73" />`
- ...one last regex!
- `start` is assigned `0` but isn't actually used anymore
- `end` is `m.end() - 3` because we know that there are exactly three characters from the end of the number (the value of the stock) until the `/` character (including the character): `"`,  and `/`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It helped me a lot . Thanks  . I am grateful